# JAX-WS Authentication SoapUI vs. Client application

Tags: security, authentication, soap, jax-ws, soapui

I need to create an SOAP client with JAX-WS on JBoss.
The Problem is I cannot get past the authentication.

I have a test implemented in SoapUI which works when I set the request properties username and password[image: soap ui screenshot]

With the following code

```
        URL kbaURL = new URL("http://...");
        IkfzService ikfzService = new IkfzService(kbaURL);
        IkfzPortType ikfzPortType = ikfzService.getIkfzSOAP();
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)ikfzPortType).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "...");
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "...");
```

Where URL, username und password are the same like in SOAPUI I am getting

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException:
Failed to create service.
...
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: 
Problem parsing 'http://..'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 
401 for URL: http://..
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you really trying to use `URL kbaURL = new URL("http://...");` as your SOAP web service endpoint?  I think the `Problem parsing 'http://..` sort of indicates you are.  The SOAP endpoint "WSDL" should be set to the same one you are using in SOAP-UI

Answer (score 0):

This should be a basic example of what you're trying to accomplish - let me know if you need more help or clarification

```
//the WSDL/webservice endpoint
private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/MyWebService?wsdl";

URL url = new URL(WSDL_URL);
QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mycompany.com/", MyWebServiceImpl");

Service theWSService = Service.create(url, qname);

//returns the interface for MyWebServiceImpl
TheWSServiceIF port = theWSService.getPort(TheWSServiceIF.class);

//Setup Security
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, WS_URL);

Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
requestHeaders.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("myUserName"));
requestHeaders.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("myPasword"));
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
/**********************************************************************/

//actually call the web service method, print results
System.out.println(port.getMyWebServiceData());
```

Comment: Did the answer help Hans?